# When considering the commutative ring $R$ over itself, if its submodule is free, then the submodule equals to the module?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

When considering the commutative ring $R$ over itself, then this $R$-module is isomorphic to $R$, but if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then it is a submodule, if this submodule is free too, then it is isomorphic to $R^n$, as its in $R$, thus it is isomorphic to $R$, it is a contradiction.Any mistake I made in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, your ideal is isomorphic to $R^n$ but this isomorphism is quite abstract and your proof shows nothing.
Counter-example : the ideal $2 \mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Exercise : show that your property is true if and only if $R$ is a field.

Comment: Consider if every submodule of every free $R$-module is free(where $R$ is a commutative ring),then $R$ over itself is finitely generated module which is isomorphic to $R$, to the ideal r$R$, as its a submodule of the free module, then it is free, thus it should be isomorphic to $R^n$, thus it should be isomorphic to $R$, then the submodule equals to the module. I can't understand the contradiction here.

Comment: Do you agree that I gave you a counter-example. Maybe, you want to say that $R$ is isomorphic to its ideal? This is not the same as saying that they are equal...

Comment: Under $Z$, I don't think 2$Z$ is a free $Z$-submodule

Comment: Because, if it is free then it should be isomorphic to $Z^n$

Comment: For a PID, every submodule of a free module is free. So the counterexample is a very good one.

Comment: A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is just an abelian group. And, AS abelian groups, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic by the map sending $n$ to $2n$.

Comment: @joseph it IS isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^1$. What is your objection?

Comment: In your question, you write "is the submodule equal to the module". This answer is no; but they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Jeremy Daniel, that makes sense, thank you. I repeat my badly written comments because I want to get some ideas from other people, is that not allowed?

Comment: I have one more question, if r∈R, then r∈R is an ideal of R, then if it is a free submodule over R, why rb can not be 0, to any b∈R?

Comment: $rb$ can be zero if your ring is not a domain. So if $r$ in $R$ is a divisor of zero, the map from $R$ to $rR$ given by multiplication by $r$ is a morphism of $R$-modules, which is surjective by definition but not injective.

Comment: @Jeremy Daniel Thank you, but If every submodule of every free R-module is free, then R is a principal ideal domain. Thus here R should be a domain. I just want to prove why it is a domain,if its a domain, then rb can not be 0, if b is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are rings for which every right ideal is free, and it's even possible for them to have rank more than 1. If such a ring is also commutative, it is a principal ideal domain, and all the ideals are isomorphic (as modules) to the ring.

Comment: Consider if every submodule of every free R-module is free(where R is a commutative ring),then R over itself is finitely generated module which is isomorphic to R, to the ideal rR, as its a submodule of the free module, then it is free, thus it should be isomorphic to Rn, thus it should be isomorphic to R, then the submodule equals to the module. I can't understand the contradiction here.

Comment: @Joseph the problem with you reasoning is the statement "isomorphic to R and contained in R implies equal to R" which is plain nonsense. Jeremy gave a clear example that this is not so.

Answer (score 1):

@Joseph: Isomorphisms are not same as equality. If the natural inclusion map is an isomorphism, then you can say that it is actually an equality. Otherwise not in general. For example, take the ring $A := k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots],$ k is a field and let $B := k[x_2, x_3, x_4, \cdots].$ Then $B$ is a subring of $A$, and it is also isomorphic to $A$ (why?). But clearly $B \neq A.$ Note that in this case, the natural inclusion is not an isomorphism. You have to produce an isomorphism abstractly.

Comment: Let me acknowledge that, what I wrote above (except the example) was already pointed out by  Jeremy Daniel and rschwieb. Jeremy Daniel also provided a good counter-example.